# To align equation

Tags: equations

How to align the equation below with number in center of equation? And I need that the equations have same length.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
VAR(X)&=\frac{1}{12m}\sum_{u \in \Omega}\left( a_{u1}^2 +a_{u2}^2 + a_{u3}^2 + a_{u1}a_{u2} + a_{u1}a_{u3} + a_{u2}a_{u3}\right) - \left[ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{u \in \Omega} \frac{a_{u1} + a_{u2} + a_{u3}}{3} \right]^2\\
VAR(Y)&=\frac{1}{12m}\sum_{u \in \Omega}\left( b_{u1}^2 +b_{u2}^2 + b_{u3}^2 + b_{u1}b_{u2} + b_{u1}b_{u3} + b_{u2}b_{u3}\right) - \left[ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{u \in \Omega} \frac{b_{u1} + b_{u2} + b_{u3}}{3} \right]^2
\label{eq:variancia_amostral_triangulo_x_y}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Wrong mode.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the trick....  and makes VAR look less like V times A times 
R.

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \mathrm{VAR}(X)&=\frac{1}{12m}\sum_{u \in \Omega}\left( a_{u1}^2 +a_{u2}^2 + a_{u3}^2 + a_{u1}a_{u2} + a_{u1}a_{u3} + a_{u2}a_{u3}\right) \\
     & \qquad - \left[ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{u \in \Omega} \frac{a_{u1} + a_{u2} + a_{u3}}{3} \right]^2\\
    \mathrm{VAR}(Y)&=\frac{1}{12m}\sum_{u \in \Omega}\left( b_{u1}^2 +b_{u2}^2 + b_{u3}^2 + b_{u1}b_{u2} + b_{u1}b_{u3} + b_{u2}b_{u3}\right) 
    \\
    &\qquad - \left[ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{u \in \Omega} \frac{b_{u1} + b_{u2} + b_{u3}}{3} \right]^2
    \end{aligned}
     \label{eq:variancia_amostral_triangulo_x_y}
   \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: "VAR" is probably short for "variance". Since the `amsmath` package is being loaded, it's a good idea to define `\VAR` as a math operator, say, `\DeclareMathOperator{\VAR}{VAR}`, and then write `VAR(X)=...`. For an extra bonus point, don't autosize the square brackets on lines 2 and 4; instead, use `\biggl[` and `\biggr]`.

Comment: `\label` should go outside the `aligned`

Comment: @Mico Got told off for using `\DeclareMathOperator` for `Value at Risk` in the past....  True, that had indices as opposed to an argument, but it's no less an operator than the variance.....

Comment: @egreg: fixed...