# How to get this equation aligned?

Tags: equations

How can I align this equation?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial t}= & \underbrace{-\gamma \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{B}_{\text {eff }}}_{\text {precesion }}+\underbrace{\frac{\alpha}{M} \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial t}}_{\text {damping }}\\
-\underbrace{b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial x}-\beta b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial x}}_{\text {STT }} \\
& +\underbrace{\theta_i^{S H} c_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \hat{y}}_{\text {SHE STT }}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Right now, it looks like as shown here in this [image].

I want (1)  the LHS to move towards the leftmost position, (2) the second and third line to lie under the first term aligned

Comment: Did you check this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325365/to-align-equation ?

Comment: If you don't have a `&` in a line (as in the second line), then LaTeX treats it as if the missing `&` is at the end of your line.  So (1) after the equal sign, (2) the end of the line, and (3) the beginning of the line have all aligned in your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this suits with you??

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial t}&=  \underbrace{-\gamma \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{B}_{\text {eff }}}_{\text {precesion }}+\underbrace{\frac{\alpha}{M} \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial t}}_{\text {damping }}\\
&\quad-\underbrace{b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial x}-\beta b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial x}}_{\text {STT }} \\
&\quad +\underbrace{\theta_i^{S H} c_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \hat{y}}_{\text {SHE STT }}
\end{split}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, corrected and thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will do an alignment with `flalign` (for example).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial t}={}&  \underbrace{-\gamma \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{B}_{\mathrm{eff}}}_{\text {precesion }}+\underbrace{\frac{\alpha}{M} \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial t}}_{\mathrm{damping }}&&\\\nonumber
{}&-\underbrace{b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial x}-\beta b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial x}}_{\mathrm{STT }} +\underbrace{\ \theta_i^{S H} c_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \hat{y}}_{\textup{SHE STT}}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial t}={}&  \underbrace{-\gamma \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{B}_{\mathrm{eff}}}_{\text {precesion }}+\underbrace{\frac{\alpha}{M} \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial t}}_{\mathrm{damping }}&&\\\nonumber
{}&-\underbrace{b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial x}-\beta b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial x}}_{\mathrm{STT }}\\\nonumber
{}&+\underbrace{\ \theta_i^{S H} c_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \hat{y}}_{\textup{SHE STT}}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the alignment point to the lines after the first.

I recommend using `\ubrace` as defined, in order to overcome a subtle spacing issue of `\underbrace`. Also, I find the underbrace in the second line to be ambiguous: is the STT the first item *minus* the second?

Therefore I decided to put the signs inside the underbraced equation, but needed a trick to get the spacing right.

I also suggest `\pder` to save typing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\0}[1]{{\mspace{#1\medmuskip}}}
\begin{aligned}
\pder{\mathbf{M}}{t} ={}
& \0{+}\ubrace{\0{-}-\gamma \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{B}_{\textup{eff}}\vphantom{\frac{a}{M}}}
         {\textup{precession}}
  \0{+}\ubrace{\0{-}+\frac{\alpha}{M} \mathbf{M} \times \pder{\mathbf{M}}{t}}
          {\textup{damping}}
\\
& \0{+}\ubrace{\0{-}-b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \pder{\mathbf{M}}{x}
          -\beta b_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \pder{\mathbf{M}}{x}}
         {\textup{STT}}
\\
& \0{+}\ubrace{\0{-}+\theta_i^{S H} c_i^j \mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{M} \times \hat{y}}
         {\textup{SHE STT}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another small fix is the phantom in the first line, so the braces are typeset at the same level.

Comment: It might look and read better with the underbrace for "damping" to start after the `+` sign.

Comment: @yannisl Possibly. I chose to be uniform.